# How can I set a search domain (and other resolv.conf parameters) in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, dhcp, networkmanager

I like Ubuntu's NetworkManager -- it does a great job keeping track of all my WiFi parameters and passwords. However, when I actually plug in an Ethernet cable, the frustration begins.

When hooked up to my work LAN, I'd like to force a particular domain search path. But I can't just edit resolv.conf, since NetworkManager will always overwrite it. And I can't change the settings on the DHCP server.

As a total hack, I set up a script to run whenever the network is brought up. It looks at resolv.conf, and if it's the one from the work LAN, it overwrites it. However, this doesn't work well enough -- it seems that periodically resolv.conf will get overwritten by something that doesn't trigger my script.

Is there a less hacky way to do this? Or even a more hacky way, provided that it actually works?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu and a connection named "Wired connection"

edit `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection` and add the following:

```
[ipv4]
method=auto
dns-search=a1.domain.com;a2.domain.com;a3.domain.com;
```

Comment: this works for fedora too.  but there is dns and dns-search settings. what is the difference ?

Comment: @PeterMoore dns is the DNS IP address you are using, dns-search is the domains that you will search your hosts in, for example, in case you set  dns-search `domain.com` if you ping host name `myhost` it will automatically search for `myhost.domain.com` (dns-search is optional)

Answer (score 5):

I think you can set your "search domain" right in Network Manager.

1. Right-click on nm-applet
2. Select **Edit Connections**
3. Click on **auto eth0** and select **Edit**
4. click on the **ipv4 Settings** tab, and fill in the **search domsins** line (may have to select **automatic (DHCP) addresses only** from the dropdown list.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: nice tip! (BTW it is left-click, actually.)

Comment: I tried that, and the search line was added to resolv.conf but all the nameserver entries were removed!

Answer (score 2):

If you add the proper parameters to your dhclient.conf, they will get put into the resolv.conf when it is rewritten

```
supersede domain-name "mydomain.com"
```

might be what you're looking for.  Check the man page or online documentation for dhclient for more details.

Comment: Cool! So if I want the line "search local mydomain.com" to always be in /etc/resolv.conf, what's the supersede line for that?

Answer (score -1):

https://www.netroby.com/view/3630#.U2mTfHVdUc0
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-when-resolv-conf-is-being-overwritten

You can write nameserver in the config right before the DNS server with nameserver x.x.x.x